# Filtering/deleting items from a Redis set

Tags: lua, redis

I am caching bus stop arrival times and route IDs in a Redis set, with one set per bus stop. I'm looking for an easy way to update these sets, removing arrival times in the past while preserving any other future arrivals. How can I filter a set according to certain criteria at write time?

A set that has not been written to in a while will expire, so I'm only concerned about sets that are continually being updated, essentially setting an expiry at an element level instead of a set level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will filter out values less than `KEYS[2]` (a UNIX timestamp in my case, passed as such because LUA scripts in Redis can't access date/time info). The second clause then adds any additional values passed to the script.

```
local members_expired = 0 -- number of members expired/removed
local additions_attempted = 0 -- number of SADD attempts
local members_added = 0 -- number of members successfully added
local key = KEYS[1] -- the key of the set to update
local current_time = KEYS[2] -- the current timestamp

-- iterate through existing members and "expire" (remove) any members
-- less than the current time
for index, value in next, redis.call('SMEMBERS', key) do
    -- interpret the first 10 characters of the member as a timestamp,
    -- allowing us to include additional data such as the route ID
    if string.sub(value, 1, 10) < current_time then
        redis.call('SREM', key, value);
        members_expired = members_expired + 1
    end
end

-- iterate through provided members and attempt to insert them into the
-- target set
for index, value in next, ARGV do
    additions_attempted = additions_attempted + 1
    members_added = members_added + redis.call('SADD', key, value)
end

-- number of duplicate members
local duplicates_ignored = additions_attempted - members_added

-- entire set will expire in 1 week unless it's updated in the meantime
redis.call('EXPIRE', key, 604800)

return {
    members_added,
    members_expired,
    duplicates_ignored
}
```

The script takes the following parameters:

- "Keys"

  - Key of set to update
  - Current UNIX timestamp (not accessible from within Redis, so needs to be passed from outside)
- Values

  - One or more values in the format `[timestamp]:[extra_data]`, for instance `1474904925:route_123`

It returns an array with the following values:

1. Number of elements added to the set.
2. Number of elements with timestamps in the past removed from the set.
3. Number of failed insertions, presumed to be duplicates already in the set.

PHP example (using [Predis](https://github.com/nrk/predis)):

```
$predis = new Predis\Client();
$time = time();

// some time in the future to add to the set
$values = [
    ($time + 3600) . ':route_123',
    ($time + 7200) . ':route_123',
    ($time + 7200) . ':route_456',
    ($time + 7200) . ':route_456', // this is a duplicate
];

$filter_script = <<<LUA
local members_expired = 0 -- number of members expired/removed
local additions_attempted = 0 -- number of SADD attempts
local members_added = 0 -- number of members successfully added
local key = KEYS[1] -- the key of the set to update
local current_time = KEYS[2] -- the current timestamp

-- iterate through existing members and "expire" (remove) any members
-- less than the current time
for index, value in next, redis.call('SMEMBERS', key) do
    -- interpret the first 10 characters of the member as a timestamp,
    -- allowing us to include additional data such as the route ID
    if string.sub(value, 1, 10) < current_time then
        redis.call('SREM', key, value);
        members_expired = members_expired + 1
    end
end

-- iterate through provided members and attempt to insert them into the
-- target set
for index, value in next, ARGV do
    additions_attempted = additions_attempted + 1
    members_added = members_added + redis.call('SADD', key, value)
end

-- number of duplicate members
local duplicates_ignored = additions_attempted - members_added

-- entire set will expire in 1 week unless it's updated in the meantime
redis.call('EXPIRE', key, 604800)

return {
    members_added,
    members_expired,
    duplicates_ignored
}
LUA;

// We can run the script directly...
list($members_added, $members_expired, $duplicates_ignored) = $predis->eval(
    $filter_script,
    2,
    'somekey',
    $time,
    $values[0],
    $values[1],
    $values[2],
    $values[3]
);

echo "Members added: $members_added\n";
echo "Members expired: $members_expired\n";
echo "Duplicate members ignored: $duplicates_ignored\n";
echo "\n";

// or save it for faster execution if we're going to run repeatedly
$members_added_total = 0;
$members_expired_total = 0;
$duplicates_ignored_total = 0;
$filter_script_sha = $predis->script('LOAD', $filter_script);

foreach ($values as $value) {
    list($members_added, $members_expired, $duplicates_ignored) =
        $predis->evalsha($filter_script_sha, 2, 'somekey', $time, $value);

    echo "[$members_added, $members_expired, $duplicates_ignored]\n";

    $members_added_total += $members_added;
    $members_expired_total += $members_expired;
    $duplicates_ignored_total += $duplicates_ignored;
}

echo "Members added: $members_added_total\n";
echo "Members expired: $members_expired_total\n";
echo "Duplicate members ignored: $duplicates_ignored_total\n";
```

Parameters for [`eval`](http://redis.io/commands/eval) and [`evalsha`](http://redis.io/commands/evalsha) are:

1. Script or SHA1 hash, respectively
2. Always "2" (number of arguments to pass to the `KEYS` LUA variable - see [docs](http://redis.io/commands/eval))
3. `KEYS[1]` The key to read/modify
4. `KEYS[2]` The current UNIX timestamp
5. (and up) `VALUES` Any new values to add to the set